# Get total chat and missedChats

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sample data like this.

```
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 121,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 13,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 232,
    "missedChats": 9
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000004",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 9,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000005",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000008",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
}
```

My code:

```
const dataset = [];

const websiteIds = [];
const dates = [];
const chats = [];
const missedChats = [];

let chatsSum = 0;
let missedChatsSum = 0;

function getData() {
  if (start == null && end == null) {
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.map(result => {
        console.log(result)
        let sets = {
            websiteId: result.websiteId,
            chats: result.chats,
            missedChats: result.chats,
          }
    
    chats.push(result.chats)
    missedChats.push(result.missedChats)
    
    if (!websiteIds.includes(result.websiteId)) {
      websiteIds.push(result.websiteId)
      for (let x = 0; x < websiteIds.length; x++) {
        if (sets.websiteId == websiteIds[x]) {
          dataset.push(sets)
        }
        if (result.websiteId == websiteIds[x]) {
          dataset[x].chats += result.chats
          dataset[x].missedChats += result.missedChats
        }
      }
    }
  })
})


 } else {
    console.log('date given')
  }
}
```

My expected output should be like this

```
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 500, // total number of chat in this websiteID
    "missedChats": 15 // total number of chat in this websiteID
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 100, // total number of chat in this websiteID
    "missedChats": 50// total number of chat in this websiteID
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 200, // total number of chat in this websiteID
    "missedChats": 25 // total number of chat in this websiteID
}
```

I'm trying to get the total sum of the chat and missedchats per my websiteID. Is there a way on how I can get the data on the given example? When I'm trying to run my code it doesn't sums up the chat and misschats it only gets the first value per websiteID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce to sum the values:

```js
function sum(data) {
    return Object.values(data.reduce((acc, el) => {
        if (!(el.websiteId in acc)) {
            acc[el.websiteId] = el;
        } else {
            acc[el.websiteId].chats += el.chats;
            acc[el.websiteId].missedChats += el.missedChats;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {}));
}


const data = [{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 121,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 13,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 232,
    "missedChats": 9
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000004",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 9,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000005",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000008",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000007",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000006",
    "date": "2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 0,
    "missedChats": 1
}];

console.log(sum(data));
```

The block

```
data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    if (!(el.websiteId in acc)) {
        acc[el.websiteId] = el;
    } else {
        acc[el.websiteId].chats += el.chats;
        acc[el.websiteId].missedChats += el.missedChats;
    }
    return acc;
}, {})
```

creates an object using `websiteId` as key containing the summed values. `Object.values` returns the values as array.

Comment: may I know what is the el and acc? just encountered it now

Comment: @PinkyPromise `acc` is the common name for the accumulator and `el` is the common name for the element in a reducer.

Comment: and last question, what is empty {} for?

Comment: @PinkyPromise That's the initial value for the accumulator.

Comment: Hi, what if I want to filter by date using getData(date1, date2)

Comment: @PinkyPromise You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229091/discussion-between-pinky-promise-and-thomas-sablik).